# Nextjs middleware is not able to read cookies, when deployed on vercel

Tags: authentication, next.js, cookies, vercel, vercel-middleware

I deployed the nextjs application on vercel, and nodejs application on render.

I use middleware.js in nextjs to check if the user is authenticated or not. If the cookie is present, he moves ahead, else is redirected to the signin page.

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
// import { cookies } from 'next/headers'



export function middleware(request){
    console.log("Cookies")
    console.log(request.headers.cookie)
    console.log(request.headers)
    console.log(request.cookies)
    // const cookieStore = cookies() -> Gives vercel error, edge-runtime crashed
    // console.log(cookieStore.getAll()) 
    const path = request.nextUrl.pathname
    console.log(path)
    const isPublicPath = path === '/auth/login' || path=='/auth/signup' || path=="/"
    console.log(request.cookies)
    const token = request.cookies.get('resumaniatoken')?.value || ""
    console.log("Token is",token)

    if (!isPublicPath && !token){
        console.log("NO TOKEN")
        console.log("Redirected to /auth/login from ",path)
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/auth/signin',request.nextUrl))
    }
}

export const config={
    matcher:[
        '/dashboard/:path*'
    ]
}
```

As you can see from the comments, I tried almost all the ways to get the cookie, but it is always undefined.

The cookies are present in the browser however.

[See Cookies are present here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ohg7.png)

I send the cookies via nodejs

`res.cookie('resumaniatoken', token, { httpOnly: true});`

I am expecting it to go to the protected routes, but it is not able to, since it can't read cookies. Have been stuck here for 20 days now, with reading almost all github issues in this topic

Comment: I think the issue is with `matcher`. I think It will only execute the middleware on specified paths. Try  to include `/:path*` and check if the issue resolves

[docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware#matcher)

Comment: The code executes, sets the cookie, and redirects to /dashboard. However, since /dashboard looks for, if cookie is present, it gets no cookie (not sure why) and thus user gets redirected back to the signin page